# While Dynamically creating dictionaries with a reference dictionary, why is the reference dictionaries getting modified? (Python)

Tags: python, dictionary

I was writing a Python Code that creates dictionaries dynamically,initializes it to a reference dictionary, and modifying a particular value in the dictionary. But,I found that not only I am getting unexpected results,but the reference dictionary is also getting modified.
My Code:

```
tdict={'a':'1','b':'2','c':'3'}
newdict={}
for i in range(5):
  newdict['name'+str(i)]=tdict
  newdict['name'+str(i)]['a']='value'+str(i)
  print 'tdict:  ',tdict
print 'newdict:  ',newdict
```

And the result:

```
tdict:   {'a': 'value0', 'c': '3', 'b': '2'}
tdict:   {'a': 'value1', 'c': '3', 'b': '2'}
tdict:   {'a': 'value2', 'c': '3', 'b': '2'}
tdict:   {'a': 'value3', 'c': '3', 'b': '2'}
tdict:   {'a': 'value4', 'c': '3', 'b': '2'}
newdict:   {'name4': {'a': 'value4', 'c': '3', 'b': '2'}, 'name2': {'a': 'value4', 'c': '3', 'b': '2'}, 'name3': {'a': 'value4', 'c': '3', 'b': '2'}, 'name0': {'a': 'value4', 'c': '3', 'b': '2'}, 'name1': {'a': 'value4', 'c': '3', 'b': '2'}}
```

whereas I expected my 'newdict' to be like:

```
newdict:   {'name4': {'a': 'value4', 'c': '3', 'b': '2'}, 'name2': {'a': 'value2', 'c': '3', 'b': '2'}, 'name3': {'a': 'value3', 'c': '3', 'b': '2'}, 'name0': {'a': 'value0', 'c': '3', 'b': '2'}, 'name1': {'a': 'value1', 'c': '3', 'b': '2'}}
```

Can anyone please help me figuring out why this is happening? Also, why is the reference dictionary 'tdict' getting changed when I am not assigning any any value to it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are storing a reference to `tdict` in every value of your `newdict` dictionary:

```
newdict['name'+str(i)]=tdict
```

You are then modifying the key `'a'` of `tdict` by doing

```
# newdict['name'+str(i)] is a reference to tdict
newdict['name'+str(i)]['a']='value'+str(i)
# this is equivalent to doing
tdict['a']='value'+str(i)
```

What you maybe want is storing a copy of `tdict` in your newdict dictionary:

```
newdict['name'+str(i)]=dict(tdict)
```

Creating a new dictionary by using an existing dictionary as constructor argument creates a shallow copy where you can assign new values to existing keys. What you cannot (or what you don't want) is modifying mutable values in this dictionary. Example:

```
>>> a={'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': [1,2,3]}
>>> b=dict(a)
>>> b['a']=9
>>> a
{'a': 1, 'c': [1, 2, 3], 'b': 2}
>>> b
{'a': 9, 'c': [1, 2, 3], 'b': 2}
>>> b['c'].append(99)
>>> a
{'a': 1, 'c': [1, 2, 3, 99], 'b': 2}
>>> b
{'a': 9, 'c': [1, 2, 3, 99], 'b': 2}
```

If you want to modify mutable values in a dictionary you need to create a deep copy:

```
>>> import copy
>>> a={'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': [1,2,3]}
>>> b=copy.deepcopy(a)
>>> b['a']=9
>>> b['c'].append(99)
>>> a
{'a': 1, 'c': [1, 2, 3], 'b': 2}
>>> b
{'a': 9, 'c': [1, 2, 3, 99], 'b': 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is just cause you are making a reference to tdict and not a copy. In order to copy you can either use

```
newdict['name'+str(i)] = tdict.copy()
```

or

```
newdict['name'+str(i)] = dict(tdict)
```

Hope it helps