# Python3 List of Dictionary

Tags: python, list

I meet a strange phenomenon while dealing with list of dictionary in python3

```
oldlist = [{'name':'cheng'}]
ages = '18,20'
newlist = []

for ele in oldlist:
    for age in ages.split(','):
       ele['age'] = age
       newlist.append(ele)

print(newlist)

The result is :
[{'name': 'cheng', 'age': '20'}, {'name': 'cheng', 'age': '20'}]

What I am expected is 
[{'name': 'cheng', 'age': '18'}, {'name': 'cheng', 'age': '20'}]
```

Comment: Use one loop, not two loops.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [While Dynamically creating dictionaries with a reference dictionary, why is the reference dictionaries getting modified? (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12053218/while-dynamically-creating-dictionaries-with-a-reference-dictionary-why-is-the)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `ele` is still referencing the same dictionary in the next iteration. You'll need to create a copy. One way is to cast it to a dict:

```
for ele in oldlist:
    for age in ages.split(','):
        ele['age'] = age
        newlist.append(dict(ele))
```

or better yet, don't use `oldlist`, simply use `ele` itself for initialization:

```
ele = {'name':'cheng'}

for age in ages.split(','):
    ele['age'] = age
    newlist.append(ele)
```

Output:

```
[{'name': 'cheng', 'age': '18'}, {'name': 'cheng', 'age': '20'}]
```